# How to implement Ordered properly

Tags: scala

I have a trait

```
trait Weight  {
    def getWeight: Int
}
```

Multiple classes inherits it, example:

```
case class Test(n: Int) extends Weight  {
  override def getWeight: Int = n
}
```

Now i want to add sorting ability to all `Weight` subclasses. I added `Ordered` to `Weight`:

```
trait Weight extends Ordered[Weight] {

  def getWeight: Int

  override def compare(that: Weight): Int = this.getWeight.compareTo(that.getWeight)
}
```

Try sorting:

```
val seq = Seq(Test(1), Test(4), Test(3), Test(2))

seq.sorted // error
```

And it's not compiles:

> Error:(74, 6) diverging implicit expansion for type
>   scala.math.Ordering[A$A254.this.Test] starting with method $conforms
>   in object Predef seq.sorted;}
>       ^

Whats i am doing wrong?

Comment: I think problem is about "this" in trait Weight. on Trait you can't use "this" because you can't instance a trait

Comment: I think no, because only `sorted`, which implicitly uses Ordering raises error.

Comment: that because, I think, is first time on your code where you call "compare" method - But I could be terribly wrong

Comment: I just tried call `Test(1).compareTo(Test(2))` and it's ok

Comment: Ok sorry I was wrong. But what about use Ordering trait and not Ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work because `Ordered[T]` is invariant in `T`, meaning that `Ordered[Weight]` has no relationship with `Ordered[A]`. You would need to specify that in the sub-classes.

You could use an implicit `Ordering` rather than an `Ordered`.

```
trait Weight{
  def getWeight : Int
}

object Weight{
  implicit def ordering[T <: Weight] : Ordering[T] = Ordering.by(w => w.getWeight)
}
  case class A(w : Int) extends Weight{
  def getWeight = w
}
case class B(w : Int) extends Weight{
  def getWeight = w
}

import Weight._

Seq(A(1),B(2),B(0),A(3),A(-3)).sorted
```

Will result in:

```
List(A(-3), B(0), A(1), B(2), A(3))
```

Note that this solution relies on an `Ordering[Int]` to be available (which is, by default).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution a bit different than mdm. Since `sorted` takes an implicit of `Ordering`, you can do the following:

```
seq.sorted(Ordering[Weight])
```